# Воспроизведение mp3 из FileStream

Tags: c#, mp3, filestream

Как можно стандартными библиотеками C# воспроизвести *mp3* из `FileStream`?
Пробовал при помощи `System.Media.SoundPlayer`, но в ней можно только *WAV*.

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою неточность, да, именно воспроизвести.

Comment: В стандартных библиотеках нет воспроизведения mp3 из потока. И вообще воспроизведения mp3 нет - wmp.dll - это не часть фреймворка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в проект ссылку на `wmp.dll (\windows\system32\wmp.dll)`
Затем:

```
 WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); 
 wplayer.URL = "sound.mp3";
 wplayer.controls.play();
```

Comment: Да, но это открывается файл по пути, а мне надо из FileStream().

Comment: @kxxko: тогда только http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Была надежда, что будет стандартное решение, без посторонних библиотек ;)

Comment: @kxxko: попробуй еще new MediaStreamSource API to stream a MPEG-Layer 3 (MP3) audio file. может подойдет тебе.

Comment: @cpp_user: Возможно, ваш комментарий насчёт naudio стоит добавить в ответ.

Comment: @VladD: это скорее не ответ, а совет - потому что не содержит кода как это сделать на naudio.

Comment: @cpp_user: Может быть, тогда стоит ещё чуть-чуть не полениться, и добавить пару строк кода?

Comment: @VladD: Кода там реально много, но там есть пример в исходниках NAudio-Source\NAudioDemo\Mp3StreamingDemo

Comment: Всем спасибо. Сделал, помогло ;)