# Аудио плеер на C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, аудио, mp3

Хочу сделать плеер на C#. Сугубо для аудио.
Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли в .NET библиотеки для работы с аудио файлами (wav,mp3,ogg и тд). Если нет, то, может быть, какие-то сторонние решения/библиотеки есть. Подскажите

Comment: [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Воспроизведение mp3 из FileStream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431778/%d0%92%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-mp3-%d0%b8%d0%b7-filestream)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449241/Воспроизведение-потокового-аудио-net

Comment: Я бы посоветовал libvlc с ее портом на .net [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet), плагины оставить только те которые необходимы, в том числе выпилить `QtControl`